# Render key and value of a field

Tags: 8, theming, entities

I have a field (list integer) and I would like to render its keys and values. I found field.html.twig but within I only have access to item.content which is the value. I would also like to access the key.
I also had a look to `theme_preprocess_field(&$variables)` but I'm not able to get the correct keys.

I tried

```
  foreach ($variables['items'] as $key => $item) {
    $variables['items'][ $key ]['key'] = $key;
  }
```

Unfortunatelly this only gives me the array positions 0,1,2 ... But I would like to have the actual keys from my list, i.e.

100|red
200|green
300|blue
400|black
...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get the list field key and value

```
function themename_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {

    if ($variables['field_name'] == 'field_test') {

        foreach ($variables['items'] as $key => $item) {
            $list_field_value = $item['content']['#markup'];
            $list_field_key = $variables['element']['#items'][$key]->getString();
        }

    }

}
```

**Note:** replace `field_test` with the actual field machine name, **do not replace `field_name`.**